# Выключение питания устройства

Tags: android

Необходимо корректно выключить устройство (завершить работу андроида). Есть два пути которые везде описаны, но они не подходят.

1. `Intent i = new
   Intent("android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN");
   i.putExtra("android.intent.extra.KEY_CONFIRM", true);
   startActivity(i);`

   этот вариант не устраивает, т.к. используется язык (локаль) системы в выскакивающем диалоге. А мне нужно что бы использовался язык программы (доступа к системным настройкам языка нет).

---

2. `PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
   powerManager.reboot(null);`
   этот вариант тоже не совсем подходит, т.к. это приводит к перезагрузке а не к выключению.

Исходя из этого, вопрос: Можно ли поменять язык надписей активности, которую я вызываю через интент, не используя настройки системы? Как завершить работу ОС используя класс PowerManager?

Comment: А что такое *язык активности* - поясните более подробно

Comment: Я имею ввиду русский, английский и т.д. Язык на котором отображаются надписи диалогового окна.